# Why resolving a collection also create 1 element?

Tags: mono, autofac

I am using Autofac 3.5.2 on Mono and when I try to register a generic collection and then resolve it I get the right instance where 1 element of the right type has already been added. To explain it in code:

```
class Fake {}

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Fake>();
bilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(List<>));

var scope = builder.Build();

var list = scope.Resolve<List<Fake>>();

Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // => prints 1!
```

Is this to be expected? Why? How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Autofac* has [built-in support for collection](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b) and will by default try to use the constructor with the most available arguments when it resolves a service.

> Autofac automatically uses the constructor for your class with the most parameters that are able to be obtained from the container
>   
>   > http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#register-by-type

`List<T>` contains a constructor which take a `IEnumerable<T>`. 
When *Autofac* resolve `List<Fake>` it will choose the constructor with `IEnumerable<T>`, then resolve `IEnumerable<T>` which will resolve all available *instance* of `T`.

If you have more than one `Fake` registered, *Autofac* will resolve all of them when you resolve. For example :

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Fake1>().As<IFake>();
builder.RegisterType<Fake2>().As<IFake>();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(List<>)); 

var scope = builder.Build();

var list = scope.Resolve<List<IFake>>();
Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // => prints 2!
```

You can specify which constructor to use when you register `List<T>`

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Fake1>().As<IFake>();
builder.RegisterType<Fake2>().As<IFake>();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(List<>)).UsingConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);

var scope = builder.Build();

var list = scope.Resolve<List<IFake>>();

Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // => prints 0!
```

Or you can ignore default behavior by using the `ContainerBuildOptions.ExcludeDefaultModules` parameter in the `Build` method

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Fake1>().As<IFake>();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(List<>)); 

var scope = builder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions.ExcludeDefaultModules);

var list = scope.Resolve<List<IFake>>();
Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // => prints 0!
```

I won't recommend removing default behaviors unless you really know what you do.

Comment: I would turn it the other way around. I would change Autofac's default configuration to allow it to ONLY resolve types with only a single public constructor [to prevent common errors and bad design](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97), unless you really know what you do.